# CSS: image size is only 5% of their width in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've just found out that my article thumbnails in IE 8 are shown only as thin stripes - as you can see on image:[image: IE8]

The web: http://jdem.cz/vzcy9

This behavior is not present in any other browser - i.e. FF 14, Opera 11, Chrome X, IE 7, IE 9 are OK.

Do you have any idea what causes this in IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the `max-wdth:99.35%` rule is doing that. Try adding a `width:auto` to the same rule that sets the fractional max-width.

In other words, change:

```
#masthead img, #featured-content img, #recent-content img, .entry-content img, .entry-thumb img, .comment-content img, .widget img {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    max-width: 99.35%;
/* Fluid images for posts, comments, and widgets */
    padding: 1px;
}
```

to

```
#masthead img, #featured-content img, #recent-content img, .entry-content img, .entry-thumb img, .comment-content img, .widget img {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    max-width: 99.35%;
    width:auto;
/* Fluid images for posts, comments, and widgets */
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: So in the end it was so simple.. I was thinking about much more complicated problems with float. Thank you @j08691